# Find a laboratory where elements are not repeated POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple tables:

```
create table computer(
    id int primary key,
    id_monitor int references monitor(id),
    laboratory_number int not null
);

create table monitor(
    id int primary key,
    id_company int references company_monitor(id),
);

create table company_monitor(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(10)
);
```

I want to get the number of a laboratory where all monitor manufacturers are different (don`t repeat). I imagined this implementation as follows: we look for how many times manufacturers repeat and find where they repeat 1 time. But the difficulty is that the total number of repetitions, and i need it in each individual laboratory.

Example:
Table "computer"

```
 id | id_monitor | id_company_cpu |    cpu_name    | ram | ssd |           gpu           | laboratory_number
----+------------+----------------+----------------+-----+-----+-------------------------+-------------------
  1 |          1 |              1 | Core i5 10800F |   8 | 500 | Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 |                 1
  2 |          2 |              2 | Ryzen 5 3600   |   8 | 500 | Radeon RX 580           |                 2
  3 |          3 |              1 | Core i5 10800F |   8 | 500 | Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 |                 1
  4 |          4 |              1 | Core i5 10800F |   8 | 500 | Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 |                 1
  5 |          5 |              2 | Ryzen 5 3600   |   8 | 500 | Radeon RX 580           |                 2
```

Table "monitor"

```
 id | id_company | diagonal | id_matrix | display_resolution
----+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------
  1 |          3 |       24 |         2 | 1980*1280
  2 |          2 |       27 |         1 | 2560*1440
  3 |          3 |       24 |         3 | 1980*1280
  4 |          3 |       24 |         1 | 1980*1280
  5 |          2 |       24 |         3 | 1980*1280
```

Table "company_monitor"

```
 id |  name
----+---------
  1 | ASUS
  2 | ACER
  3 | SAMSUNG
```

Query result should be like this (result: laboratory number 1, since all monitor manufacturers are different in it, laboratory number 2 has the same):

```
labalatory_number
-----------------
        1
```

I made this request:

```
select  monitor.id_company, count(*)
    from monitor join computer on computer.id_monitor = monitor.id 
        group by monitor.id_company
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Where's the manufacturer?

Comment: @TheImpaler it`s table ```company_monitor```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out

```
with w as (
  select distinct c.laboratory_number, c.id_monitor, m.id_company
    from computer c join monitor m on c.id_monitor = m.id
)
select laboratory_number
  from w 
  group by laboratory_number
  having count(1) = count(distinct id_company)
```

Comment: no, this doesn`t work(

Comment: in labalatory_number = 1, you have 3 monitors - id: (1, 3, 4); the companies of them are (1, 3, 3); may be in this example no result at all ?

Comment: yes, i fixed it, but it doesn't solve the problem. most likely in the wrong having condition...

Comment: I confused, now the monitors (1, 3, 4) are from the same company = 3. So the result will be empty.
Shouldn't they all be from different companies?